# Internal storage space running low after rooting and deleting unwanted apps

Tags: insufficient-memory, samsung-galaxy-s-3-mini

I am currently using a Samsung Galaxy GT-I8190 (S3 Mini) running Android 4.1.2 and I rooted my phone in order to get more internal memory to my disposal. It worked, but only for a little while. Then the memory started getting full and pops up a "warning" to say that the storage space is running low. I have an app installed by the name of "Clean Master" and I frequently clean the "junk" files on and clean it at the advanced side too. I also do a memory boost, but nothing helps to clear out memory space. I also cleared out my clipboard of everything I had copied and I unrooted my phone to see if it would help, but the memory just got fuller again so then I rooted my phone once again to take away the unwanted apps. I also have a 4GB external memory card in my device and I've moved all the apps (part of them that could move) to the memory card, but no positive results to my liking as yet. What can I do to clear up the memory? Because I can't even update my current apps because of the lack of space. Please help! Thanks

Comment: Did you try getting rid of some apps? Or removing any downloaded content, i.e. films, books etc.

Comment: What is taking up all the space? Get a disk manager and see what is so big. Some apps (for example Bard's Tale game doesn't remove the 3.5Gb of additionial files when uninstalled and needs to be manually wiped). It's impossible to know otherwise.

Comment: Yes, I got rid of some apps, like I said, I rooted my phone so that the unwanted Google apps could be deleted. @Peanut

Comment: @RossC - I do have an app on my phone that allows me to delete all the empty files on my phone after a certain app leaves something behind - its called "Clean Master" and I cannot download any more apps as the internal space on my phone is not enough to do so.

Comment: I also only have the apps that I use normally and only one game (Candy Crush) - all my pictures and music and videos are on my external memory card. I've had this phone for just over a year now and it's the first time ever it pops up this message.

Comment: My Google Drive and my Gmail apps wouldn't even refresh to load new emails or any other content because of a lack of internal storage space